# How to adapt configure.ac to add a library target in final Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, configure, autoconf, dropbear

I'm trying to get the [dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) ssh C code to build a library instead of a binary.  Dropbear is built from generating a `configure` from `configure.ac` using `autoconf`.  The `configure` is then used to generate a `Makefile` that builds executables.  I would like to create a target for the generated `Makefile` that creates a statically linked library so that my application can link it in and have access to dropbear functionality.

Is there a straight forward way to modify the `configure.ac` to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is, however, a straightforward way to modify the `Makefile.in` for this. `Makefile.in` is the template for the `Makefile`; the `configure` script does little more than replace expressions encased in `@` in the `Makefile.in` with values it deduced during its run, so you can add rules to `Makefile.in` very nearly the same way you would to a plain Makefile.

In this particular case, you could add the following:

```
dropbearlibobjs = $(filter-out svr-main.o,$(dropbearobjs))

libdropbear.a: $(dropbearlibobjs) $(HEADERS) $(LIBTOM_DEPS) Makefile
        ar rcs $@ $(dropbearlibobjs)
```

Most of this is taken from the `dropbear:` target, except the recipe builds a static library and the translation unit that contains the `main` function is filtered out. You can then use

```
./configure
make libdropbear.a
```

to build the library.

I am not certain how easily this library can be integrated with a new program, though. The authors of dropbear almost certainly did not consider this use case when they wrote it, so portions of the code may depend on global state (such as signal handlers) that your application cannot provide, and generally there's no documented API on which you can depend. I don't know what exactly you plan to do, but this path is unlikely to be easy and straightforward.

Perhaps you would rather take a look at [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/) or [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/)? (Interestingly, the former seems to be more recent than the latter)